# Вопрос по api инстаграма

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram-api

Мне нужно достать из апи локацию, но так чтобы если ее не указано, то оставлять место под локацию пустым. Когда формирую цикл, то получается следующее, что если на фотографии не указана локация, то он ее не берет в цикл. Как можно решить задачу, чтобы выводились фотографии с геолокацией, где она указана и фотографии с пустым значением геолокации, если она не указана

```js
var keyInst = '7479478511.321a9bc.e30cbb600799495da4ef993a2f43a76c',
    countInst = '3',
    linkInst = 'http://instagram.com/';
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=' + keyInst + '&count=' + countInst + '',
    success: function(data) {
        var linkInstButton = data.data[0].user.username;
        for (var i = 0; i < countInst; i++) {
            var username = data.data[i].user.full_name,
                text = data.data[i].caption.text,
                userpic = data.data[i].user.profile_picture,
                url = data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url,
                link = data.data[i].link,
                city = data.data[i].location.name;
            $('.inst-list').append('<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank" class="inst-list--el"><div class="meta"><div class="img"><img src="' + userpic + '" alt="' + username + '"></div><div class="text"><p class="name">' + username + '</p><p class="time">' + city + '</p></div></div><div class="image"><img src="' + url + '" alt="' + text + '"></div><div class="detail"><p class="name">' + username + '<span>' + text + '</span></p></div></a>');
        }
        $('.inst-list--btn a').attr('href', linkInst + linkInstButton);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="inst-list"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так?

```
city = data.data[i].location ? data.data[i].location.name : "not found";
```

```js
var keyInst = '7479478511.321a9bc.e30cbb600799495da4ef993a2f43a76c',
    countInst = '3',
    linkInst = 'http://instagram.com/';
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=' + keyInst + '&count=' + countInst + '',
    success: function(data) {
        var linkInstButton = data.data[0].user.username;
        for (var i = 0; i < countInst; i++) {
            var username = data.data[i].user.full_name,
                text = data.data[i].caption.text,
                userpic = data.data[i].user.profile_picture,
                url = data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url,
                link = data.data[i].link,
                city = data.data[i].location ? data.data[i].location.name : "not found";
            $('.inst-list').append('<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank" class="inst-list--el"><div class="meta"><div class="img"><img src="' + userpic + '" alt="' + username + '"></div><div class="text"><p class="name">' + username + '</p><p class="time">' + city + '</p></div></div><div class="image"><img src="' + url + '" alt="' + text + '"></div><div class="detail"><p class="name">' + username + '<span>' + text + '</span></p></div></a>');
        }
        $('.inst-list--btn a').attr('href', linkInst + linkInstButton);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="inst-list"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```